# Enter function when searching not working

Tags: javascript, html, search, onclick

I have tried the code below yet when I press enter, nothing happens (it should perform the search function).

```
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      prepareSearch($('#searchBox'), {
        'searchLine': '.searchTarget div.product',
        'searchSightPoint': 'div.stand, span.apron, div.aircraft, div.image',
        'fade': true,
        'contrastString': false
      });
      $('#standsearch').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
      });
    });
    var input = document.getElementById("searchBox");
    input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
      if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
        document.getElementById("btn").click();
      }
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="row" id="standsearch">
    <form class="form-search" action="#standsearch">
      <div class="input-append">
        <input type="text" id="searchBox" class="span2 search-query" placeholder="Search Stands" />
        <button type="button" id="btn" class="btnsearch">Find</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
```

I have tried using onclick="" however I am unsure what I should add within this.

Comment: You don't have an element with id 'standardsearch', first replace `$('#standsearch')` to `$('.form-search').` to access the form by its class name.

Comment: where do you catch the click event of the element with id btn ?

Comment: @Triby Doing this causes the search function to stop working completely. Also, I do have an element with id 'standsearch' (the first div element).

Comment: `div` doesn't have a `submit` method: `$('#standsearch').submit(function(e) {`

Comment: What should I do now? I have done what you've suggested but nothing has changed and I am still having the same problem. @Triby

Comment: Please edit the question to update the code and tell us what how it works, What do you expect when button is clicked and form is submitted?

Comment: @Triby The actual search function works fine. The problem is that I want to be able to press the 'enter' key and it searches. Currently, pressing the enter key does nothing.

Comment: Remove the submit listener and, if you want the button to submit the form too, change its type to `submit`

Comment: Oh perfect! That has fixed it. Thanks so much @Triby!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your main question is how to call a search function when a (simulated) click occurs on a particular element. The `onclick` attribute would probably work fine, but it's generally considered inferior to the use of an [Event Listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventListener).

It wasn't clear how bits of your more complicated code sample were supposed to fit together, so **here's clean example showing how to get the value of the input element (when ENTER is pressed) and pass that value to a search function**.

(Note that simulating a click is not actually necessary since we could simply call the same search function from both listeners, instead of having one listener rely on the other to initiate the search.)

```js
// Defines global variables
const
  searchBox = document.getElementById("searchBox"),
  btn = document.getElementById("btn"),
  haystack = document.getElementById("sentence").textContent.split(" ");


// Calls `handleEnterKeyInSearchBox` when `keyup` event happens in searchBox
searchBox.addEventListener("keyup", handleEnterKeyInSearchBox);
// Calls `handleButtonClick` when `click` event happens on btn
btn.addEventListener("click", handleButtonClick);


// Defines `handleEnterKeyInSearchBox` function
function handleEnterKeyInSearchBox(event){
  // Simulates a click on #btn if ENTER is pressed while #searchBox has focus
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    event.preventDefault();
    btn.click();
  }
}

// Defines `handleButtonClick` function
function handleButtonClick(event){
  const needle = searchBox.value; // Gets item to search for
  doSearch(needle, haystack); // Calls search function
}

// Defines a search function to use
function doSearch(theNeedle, theHaystack){
  // Gets index of word in sentence (or -1 if word is not found)
  const index = theHaystack.indexOf(theNeedle);
  // Reports result
  if(index > -1){
    console.log(`Item '${theNeedle}' found at index ${index}`);
  }
  else{
    console.log(`Could not find item '${theNeedle}'`);
  }
}
```

```html
<p id="sentence">The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</p>
<input id="searchBox" />
<button id="btn">Find</button>
```